# MySQL SUM only if one of the columns contain a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Is there a way to sum rows only when one of the columns has a certain value? I have this table:

```
| order_id | total | is_tip |
-----------------------------
|     1    |  12   |    1   |
|     1    |   3   |    0   |
|     2    |  28   |    0   |
|     2    |  15   |    0   |
|     3    |  39   |    1   |
|     3    |   8   |    1   |
```

The desired result would be:

```
| order_id | SUM(total) |
-------------------------
|     1    |     15     |
|     3    |     47     |
```

It would only sum up if one of the **is_tip** columns is equal to 1. So order IDs 1 and 3 are qualified. So far I've tried to use this query:

```
SELECT order_id, SUM(total) FROM orders HAVING COUNT(is_tip) >= 1;
```

But this query is so wrong. I'm just a beginner. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT order_id, SUM(total)
FROM orders
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING SUM(is_tip) >= 1;
```

Your query also needs a `GROUP BY`.  And I'm assuming you want a row with at least one "tip".  You can also phrase the `HAVING` clause as:

```
HAVING MAX(is_tip) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
SELECT order_id, SUM(total) FROM orders where is_tip >= 1 group by order_id;
```

`Having` can be used only where you want to filter on aggregation basis

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. :)